# launching vimdiff from diff output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, diff, vimdiff

I am trying to diff two folders using diff and launch vimdiff for each difference from a shell script

This is how I extracted filenames and made complete command using awk which I like to execute

```
 $ diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}'
 vimdiff oldfolder/a.c newfolder/a.c 
 vimdiff oldfolder/b.c newfolder/b.c
```

Now I tried

```
diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}' | bash
```

it didn't work, gives warning that `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`

also tried `bash -c` like below

```
diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}' | bash -c
```

but this gives error `bash: -c: option requires an argument`

I also tried

```
$(diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}')
```

it doesn't output at all.

This is quite useful for any developer so I am hoping to find some answer

Comment: ok added, now can you provide solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, tried it.

How about like this:

```
vimdiff $(diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print $2,$4}')
```

However this worked for me:

```
$(echo vimdiff file1 file2)
```

You can also try this:

```
</dev/tty $(diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}')
```

Oh, right, and this:

```
bash <(diff -Bbqr oldfolder newfolder | grep differ | awk '{print "vimdiff " $2,$4}')
```

You question might as well put like this way:

---

How to make this work?:

```
echo vimdiff oldfolder/a.c newfolder/a.c|bash 
echo vimdiff oldfolder/a.c newfolder/a.c|bash -c
```

---